# What will happen in heap concatenate same strings

Tags: java, string, performance

what will happen if in heap if i execute this code:

```
String text = "a" + "b" + "c";
String text = "a" + "a" + "a";
```

I know that in first variant there will be three String objects created. But in second one? Is there something being optimized in JVM?

Comment: " there will be three String objects created" Nope. The compiler treats this identically to `"abc"` and `"aaa"`.

Comment: And also: you can't execute that code, because you can't compile it (two variables with the same name).

Comment: The compiler will most probably optimize this.

Comment: *"Is there something being optimized in JVM?"* Does this matter? Do not chose your syntax for performace reasons. Always prefer the form that expresses your intent best (unless you have **proven by mesurement in your real application** that this syntax is a bottleneck.

Comment: Objects are created and stored in heap using the new keyword. String literals are created and they are stored in the string pool using above notation.

Comment: @CKing: No "probably" about it. It's in the specification. It's not that the compiler *can* optimize it; it's that it's *required* to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a common mistake everyone makes. the JLS user the word *may* and not *should* when it talks about these optimizations.

Comment: See also [Peter Lawrey's blog post about "how many objects are created"](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/common-misconception-how-many-objects.html).

Comment: @CKing the JLS doesn't use those words in this case: "Constant expressions of type String are always "interned"" is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: @AndyTurner Please see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

Comment: @CKing: I don't see the word "may" [in the section on constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). If it were a "may," you couldn't do `case "a" + "b":` -- but you can. The "may" in relation to `+` isn't relevant to the constant expression.

Comment: My bad. The section talks about two different types of operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to the question the JLS gives two information :

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) (jls-15.28) states that :

> Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to
>   share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

It means that is you use constant expressions in your code they will be put in the cache that you refer to.

But `String text = "a" + "b" + "c";` is one constant expression or are they three constant expressions as you wonder?

We have the answer to this question in another point of the JLS.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (jls-3.10.5, point 4) states indeed that :

> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>   compile time and then treated as if they were literals.

Example of constant expression :

```
"The integer " + Long.MAX_VALUE + " is mighty big."
```

It means that as soon as **the compile time** the expression above is **one** `String` literal.

In a some way, it looks like to what you are doing in your sample example:

```
String text = "a" + "b" + "c";
text = "a" + "a" + "a";
```

Consequently,     `String text = "a" + "b" + "c";`
creates a single `String`, that is `"abc"` as the constant expression  `"a" + "b" + "c"` is treated as a single literal.

It is exactly the same thing for   `text = "a" + "a" + "a";` that also is a single `String` literal for the compiler.

So finally, with you two instructions you get **two** Strings interned in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually just 1 string literal each. As described [JLS Sec 3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> A long string literal can always be broken up into shorter pieces and written as a (possibly parenthesized) expression using the string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1).

So, `"a" + "b" + "c"` and `"a" + "a" + "a"` are identical to `"abc"` and `"aaa"` by specification.

Additionally, these are constant expressions, as described in [JLS Sec 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
>
> ...
>
> Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.